# Assistance with understanding php urls

Tags: php, url, url-routing, server-side

I'm looking at websites that use php and I see`a[]=val1` instead of`b=val2`.  My question is why are there brackets in the url?  What type of code would produce this effect?

Comment: Are you talking about QueryStrings? `something.php?a[]=val1` in the address?

Comment: That's a QueryString then, it is used to easily pass data into a page without having to POST it or do any other kind of wizardry. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: Something related to multiple-select controls ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why Are the Brackets in the URL?

The brackets are in the url to indicate that `val1` is to be assigned the next position in the array `a`. If you are confused about the blank part of the bracket, look at [how php arrays work](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

### What Kind of Code Would Produce This?

As for the code that would create such a url, it could either be an explicit definition by the coder or some other script, or it could be somehow created by a form using the `method="get"` attribute.

### Example:

To create this, you can define an array as the `name` of an input field like so:

```
<form method="get">
  <input name="a[]" ... />
  <input name="a[]" ... />
  <input name="a[]" ... />
</form>
```

Or you can just make a link (the `a` tag) with this url:

```
<a href="foo.php?a[]=val1&a[]=val2&a[]=val3">Click Me!</a>
```

To parse this url with PHP, you would use the [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) variable to retrieve the values from the url:

```
<?php
  $a = $_GET['a'];

  $val1 = $a[0];
  $val2 = $a[1];
  $val3 = $a[2];
  ...

  print_r($a);
?>
```

The printout of the `print_r($a)` statement would look like this (if you wrapped it in a `<pre>` tag):

```
Array (
  a => Array (
    0 => 'val1',
    1 => 'val2',
    2 => 'val3'
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the syntax for appending a new element to an array.  There should be dollar signs preceding each variable:

```
$a[] = $val1;
```

Comment: Close, but he's talking about in the URL. It's a posted array of inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You would see input fields on the page before, like:

```
<input name="color[]" type="checkbox" value="red">
<input name="color[]" type="checkbox" value="blue">
<input name="color[]" type="checkbox" value="green">
```

wherein the user could select multiple responses and they would be available in the $color array in the $_GET (and URL) of the action page, showing up like you describe.

(Similarly it could also be hidden variables passed as an array that are not based on user input.)